# Maven does not add dependency jar files to project when importing to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Everything is loaded into the maven repository. Which is in my case located at `C:\opt\m2\repository`. I setted `M2_REPO` variable in eclipse to point to `C:\opt\m2\repository` and in command line i did `mvn clean install`.

Then I waited for 10 minutes for all the dependencies to be downloaded and went to check the repo. Everthing is downloaded to there.

Then I `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and import the project into eclipse.

Everything seems to be imported except all the maven dependencies. My project has 9409 Errors because its missing those jar files.

I did `Project -> Clean` no help.

I did `F5` on project name, no help.

I did delete and import again, no help.

Just FYI, I tried m2e plugin as well, no help.

Did I missed anything?

This is the content of .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-util/target/classes" path="ks-common-util/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-util/target/classes" path="ks-common-util/src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-util/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-util/src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-util/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-util/src/test/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-test/target/classes" path="ks-common-test/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-test/target/classes" path="ks-common-test/src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-test/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-test/src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-test/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-test/src/test/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-api/target/classes" path="ks-common-api/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-api/target/classes" path="ks-common-api/src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-impl/target/classes" path="ks-common-impl/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-impl/target/classes" path="ks-common-impl/src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-impl/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-impl/src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-impl/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-impl/src/test/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-ui/target/classes" path="ks-common-ui/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-ui/target/classes" path="ks-common-ui/src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-ui/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-ui/src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="ks-common-ui/target/test-classes" path="ks-common-ui/src/test/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

The project is structured as parent - children project. One parent project and 8 children projects. Each of them has a pom.xml file.

The parent project is fine, I can compile it. However, none of the child project works because none of the dependency gets loaded into the project.

this are the dependencies for parent pom.xml

```
  <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <!-- Test Framework Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>${derby.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbynet</artifactId>
    <version>${derby.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>${derby.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.1_3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate Transitive Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- This jar is only needed if you are using CAS with Spring Security -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <!-- <version>2.2.2</version> -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>${xercesImpl.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Metro Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
    <version>${metro.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <!-- These must be excluded for WSIT to work -->
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
        <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- stax-ex 1.0 pom making a disaster so trying 1.2 -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- CXF Dependencies -->
  <!-- Libraries not required for Java 1.6_04+ are being excluding (based cxf WHICH_JARS file) -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <!-- GWT hosted not working if this is excluded -->
      <!--
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      -->
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  // deleted to fit in SO POST

  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Velocity (used by cxf & statements) -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>${velocity.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>${velocity.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${velocity.tools.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Pom dependencies for impl specific jars -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kuali.student.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>ks-jta</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kuali.student.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>ks-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kuali.student.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>ks-metro</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kuali.student.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>ks-eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kuali.student.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>ks-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>

  <!-- GWT Dependencies -->
  // deleted in order to fit in SO post
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.kuali.rice</groupId>
    <artifactId>rice-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${kuali.rice.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jmx</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <!--
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-ojb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      -->
      <!--
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>ojb</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-ojb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      -->
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <!--
        These dependencies conflict with gwt-dev for running hosted mode via eclipse
        launch file.
      -->
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>

      <!-- JOTM - uncomment out to switch to Bitronix -->        
      <!-- 
      <exclusion>                                 
        <groupId>xapool</groupId>                 
        <artifactId>xapool</artifactId>           
      </exclusion>                                
      <exclusion>                                 
        <groupId>jotm</groupId>                   
        <artifactId>jotm</artifactId>             
      </exclusion>
       -->

      <!-- itext -->
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>itext</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  // deleted some because SO only allow 30000 characters
```

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is one of the children's pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.kuali.student</groupId>
        <artifactId>student</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.kuali.student.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>ks-common</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>KS Common</name>
    <description>Kuali Student Common</description>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>Jira</system>
        <url>https://test.kuali.org/jira/browse/KSCOR</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>ks-cxf</module>
                <module>ks-metro</module>
                <module>ks-eclipselink</module>
                <module>ks-hibernate</module>
                <module>ks-jta</module>
                <module>ks-rice-lessdep</module>
                <module>ks-common-util</module>
                <module>ks-common-test</module>
                <module>ks-common-api</module>
                <module>ks-common-impl</module>
                <module>ks-common-ui</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>skip-ui</id>
            <modules>
                <module>ks-cxf</module>
                <module>ks-metro</module>
                <module>ks-eclipselink</module>
                <module>ks-hibernate</module>
                <module>ks-jta</module>
                <module>ks-rice-lessdep</module>
                <module>ks-common-util</module>
                <module>ks-common-test</module>
                <module>ks-common-api</module>
                <module>ks-common-impl</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>kuali.nexus</id>
            <name>Nexus Repository Manager</name>
            <url>http://nexus.kuali.org/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: With the m2e plugin you don't need to do any of that manual kludging. Remove the project from your workspace, then go to File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects. Walk through the wizard and boom! Your done.

Comment: I just tried that, but it doesn't pick up any other dependency except `junit-4.4.jar`, all the dependency jars are successfully loaded in `$HOME/.m2/repository`, but not getting imported into the project.

Comment: Ignore the Maven repository for now. Do these two things - first, right click your project and select 'Properties', on the 'Java Build Path' item, select and expand "Maven Dependencies". Are your dependent libraries listed there? Second, add the contents of your POM to the question. If the POM is very large then only include the dependencies section.

Comment: 1. The dependency libraries aren't listed there except junit. 2. the pom file is too large to fit in SO post, so I had to cut off a lot.

Comment: Thats a long list of dependencies. I assume the last JUnit one you added was actually supposed to be inside the `<dependencies>` section? On your project, right click, select Maven, then 'Update Dependencies'.

Comment: I don't see update dependencies but there's an update project and I selected that, but it didn't help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26482/discussion-between-perception-and-hydrology)

Comment: the junit one is actually outside of the `<dependencyManagement>` block for some reason. That's why it is alone there.

Comment: @ssgao, Can you please share the resolution to issue which you were discussed here

Comment: Go through this post. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049135/4726362

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the m2e plugin you don't need to do any of that manual kludging. Remove the project from your workspace, then go to `File->Import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects`. Walk through the dialogs to import your project and you're done.

[image: Maven Import - Part 1]

[image: Maven Import - Part 2]

Note that if there are any `.classpath`, `.settings`, or `.project` resources in your Maven project or any of its submodules, you will need to delete them prior to performing the import (`mvn eclipse:clean` is *not* sufficient to remove them). This is because they create conflicts with the m2e setup.

Comment: indeed it is the .project, .classpath and .settings that gives me the trouble. Thanks Perception.

Comment: @VladislavBauer - be more specific about what your problem is. Maybe post a separate question?

Comment: @Perception - It seems that I've found the root of the evil.. Eclipse doesn't load correctly a root module of multi-modules project (if it contains src folder). I tried to configure src/main/java and src/main/resources in Builder Path, but it breaks my project at all.

Comment: @VladislavBauer - its not very common to have src folders in the top level (parent) module of a multi-module project. But it is possible. Post a separate question, it would be interesting to see what errors you are having.

Answer (score 6):

Try, in that order:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

mvn package

mvn eclipse:clean
```

Comment: nothing changes. I got a BUILD SUCCESS at the end. Then I go back to eclipse and hit `F5`. Still those ERRORs.

Comment: Right click your project -> maven -> disable maven nature; do a mvn eclipse:clean; right click again -> Configure -> convert to maven project

Comment: this time it picked up 1 dependency, `junit-4.4.jar`, but still missing everything else.

Comment: go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven, and check if you're using the embedded Maven that comes with maven support, or your own installation.

Comment: the embedded Mavn and the repo is $HOME/.m2/repository

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

1. The first thing you need is M2Eclipse. It's a little bit buggy but it works.(http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e)
2. Import maven project trough eclipse(M2Eclipse)
3. Do a mvn elipse:clean eclipse:eclipse on the project
4. Refresh the project in eclipse

It should work this way

Comment: Thanks but that's basically what fcm has suggested and I've done that. It didn't help.

Comment: sorry it's a long time ago i used Eclipse with maven but basically using the older M2Eclipse plugin (not the new one with connectors which causes problems) worked really fine for me. Import trough plugin, regenerate meta data with mvn eclipse plugin, refresh in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding in pom.xml, update, clean projects didn't worked. But, this worked

1 - Right Click on Maven Project.

2 - Maven -> Add dependency

3 - Enter GroupID, artifact, version.

4 - Submit

Voila, its there!
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your IDE and Re-start it .. while closing you may notice downloading of some dependency jar files.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I resolve it in this way (in project I used Maven, Spring, hibernate):

1. Help
2. Check for updates

I had to upgrade: Spring IDE (sorry, I didn't remember the all name).
After this operation everything was OK (before this operation I tried many solutions and nothing helped).